# Custom Flash message PHP

Tags: php, session, session-variables

This flash message helper is from traversymvc: a custom open-source php mvc.

My question is: is it necessary to check if (`$_SESSION[$name]`) is not empty on line 6(3rd if) when we've already made sure that it is not empty from the if condition before it.

Thanks.

```
<?php
 session_start();
 function flash($name = '', $message = '', $class = 'alert alert-success') {
  if (!empty($name)) {
    if (!empty($message) && empty($_SESSION[$name])) {
        if (!empty($_SESSION[$name])) {
            unset($_SESSION[$name]);
        }

        if (!empty($_SESSION[$name . '_class'])) {
            unset($_SESSION[$name . '_class']);
        }

        $_SESSION[$name] = $message;
        $_SESSION[$name . '_class'] = $class;
    } elseif (empty($message) && !empty($_SESSION[$name])) {
        $class = !empty($_SESSION[$name . '_class']) ? $_SESSION[$name . '_class'] : '';
        echo '<div class= "' . $class . '" id="msg-flash">' . $_SESSION[$name] . '</div>';
        unset($_SESSION[$name]);
        unset($_SESSION[$name . '_class']);
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: The 2nd if's condition (line 5) does not have a `!` before empty, so the check is not the same. If it was, then the check at line 6 is redundant.

Comment: Maybe I don't quite understand it very well.
On line 5 we make sure that $_SESSION[$name] is empty. If it is empty we again testing the same value if it is not empty on line 6. 
How can it be empty and not empty at the same time. I'm confused tho

Comment: Oh, in that case, you _did expect_ the line 5 check to be empty, (I originally thought there may have been a typo not having a `!`) ... Then no, it won't be empty and not empty at the same time, so the entire condition on line 6 can is redundant and can be eliminated.

Comment: Thanks! Wanted to make sure about that as Traversy kept it in the final code.